# data-toggle not working on button inside repeater

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page that displays a list of data within a repeater control. The repeater also displays 2 buttons on each row. I want to be able to display a bootstrap modal box when the buttons are clicked, but so far everything I have tried hasn't worked.

This is the code for the aspx page

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Current Functions</h2>
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptFunctions" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptFunctions_ItemCommand">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <td>FunctionID</td>
                <td>Function Name</td>
                <td>Function Description</td>
                <td>Read Only</td>
            </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"FunctionID") %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"FunctionName") %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"FunctionDescription") %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ReadOnly") %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("FunctionID") %>'  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-danger" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("FunctionID") %>'  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

And this is the code for the modal.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

This is what I have so far in the code behind page

```
       protected void rptFunctions_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
        {
            Response.Write("You clicked Edit button ID " + e.CommandArgument);
        }
        else if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
        {
            Response.Write("You clicked Delete button ID " + e.CommandArgument);
        }

    }
```

The above code will tell me what the name and number of the button I have clicked, but it wont display the modal form.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate ID is invalid HTML.  Use classes instead of ID.

Comment: Hi Mark would I add the class to the buttons and how would I then call it? Thanks

Comment: `$('.myclass').on('click',function(){});` for jQuery example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page is most likely posting back and that is why you are not able to see the modal. You can prevent the postback by adding return false, but you need to trigger the server side action through someother means

..asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" OnClientClick="return false;"...

Comment: Also, check if there are any script errors in the developer tools console which may be preventing the modal.

Comment: Hi Mani thanks for your reply. I have checked the console and there are no errors. I have also added the OnClientClick = "false" but it is posting back

Comment: this worked after I had rebooted my pc. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

add runat="server" to your modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" runat="server" role="dialog">
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this script in - at end of page probably.

```
<script>
function showModal()$('#myModal').modal('show');}
$('.show-my-modal').on('click',showModal);
</script>
```

Add a class to the button `CssClass="btn btn-default show-my-modal"`

As to what the modal DOES, that is a new question perhaps.

As for doing it from code behind something like this perhaps. (did not test this)

```
protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {   
      ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(),"MyFunModal", "showModal();", true);
}
```

You probably do not want both those event handlers, only the last based on your illustrated code? I will let you decide that.

Note: you might also put a call in the markup `onclick="showModal()"`